# Datatables lengthMenu not working - Server Side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

What I would like to get working is the "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 100, 200], [10, 25, 100, 200] ] and I'm using ServerSide in datatables. Option 10, 25 and 100 are working but when I select 200 it gives me an error saying "No data found in server".

[image: Link for how the error looks like]

```
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 159, 500, -1], [10, 25, 50, 159, 500, "All"]], 
"deferRender": true,
"scrollX": true,
"ajax":{
    url :"server-side-CRM.php", // json datasource
    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
    error: function(){  // error handling
       $(".crm-table-error").html("");
        $("#crm-table").append('<tbody class="crm-table-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
        $("#crm-table_processing").css("display","none");
    } 
},
```